# Mapping Buffer Movement

Tags: vimrc, macvim

How can I configure Vim and MacVim to respond to control-arrow and meta-{h,l} key-presses? The configuration below is ignored by both.

I'm using iTerm2 (version 3.2.7), Tmux (version 2.8), and Vim (version 8.1, patch 1-950).

**Vimrc:**

```
map <Esc>[1;5D <C-Left>
map <Esc>[1;5C <C-Right>
nnoremap <C-S-Tab> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Tab> :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-Left> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <M-h> :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <M-l> :bnext<CR>
```

Comment: There are a number of posts already on this topic, aren't there?

Comment: A buffer cycling post: [how to control the :bp / :bn files I loop?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18655/778)

Comment: See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/fastest-way-to-switch-to-a-buffer-in-vim

Comment: I honestly do not see why this is a new question: you are either struggling with configuration problems (see [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping)) or with [how to map Alt key?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key). I'd recommend to use the mappings proposed by [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which work cross platform and do not collide with other plugins. BTW are you sure you want to map `:bnext` to three different keys in normal mode? free key combos in normal mode are precious.